# LINQ to SQL - Combine date and time columns into a single value

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, .net-4.6.1

I'm trying to translate this SQL statement to LINQ:

```sql
SELECT sessionid, userid, CAST(sessiondate AS DATETIME) + CAST(sessiontime AS DATETIME) AS sessiondatetime FROM sometable
```

where `sessiondate` is of type `DATE` and `sessiontime` is of type `TIME`.

I've tried the following:

```cs
var query = from session in table
            select new
            {
              session.Id,
              session.UserId,
              DateTime = session.Date + session.Time
            };
```

where `table` is the return value of a `GetTable<Session>()` call on a `DataContext` instance and the `Session` class maps `sessionid` to `Id`, `userid` to `UserId`, `sessiondate` to `Date` (DateTime), and `sessiontime` to `Time` (TimeSpan).

The LINQ gets translated to this rather lengthy SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT [t0].[sessionid] AS [Id], [t0].[userid] AS [UserId], CONVERT(DateTime,DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, [t0].[sessiontime]), CONVERT(DateTime,DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEPART(MINUTE, [t0].[sessiontime]), CONVERT(DateTime,DATEADD(SECOND, DATEPART(SECOND, [t0].[sessiontime]), CONVERT(DateTime,DATEADD(MILLISECOND, DATEPART(MILLISECOND, [t0].[sessiontime]), [t0].[sessiondate])))))))) AS [DateTime] FROM [sometable] AS [t0]
```

Unfortunately, when attempting to execute that statement, it tells me that "The datepart millisecond is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date." I'm guessing it's unhappy about the `DATEADD` call with milliseconds. Is there a way to fix this?

**Edit:** note that both `session.Date` and `session.Time` are nullable.

Comment: Are you trying to sum the `sesstiondate` and `sessiontime` column values or just trying to format them to display together?

Comment: I'm trying to sum and use them for comparison later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That unfortunate data structure makes the code unfortunately ugly:

```
var query = from session in table
select new
{
    session.id,
    session.userid,
    combinedDate = new DateTime(
        session.Date.Year, session.Date.Month, session.Date.Day, 
        session.Time.Hour, session.Time.Minute, session.Time.Second, 
        session.Time.Millisecond)
};
```

Comment: I completely forgot to mention I'm using nullable values so I've been working `session.Date.Value` and `session.Time.Value`, which doesn't work properly with this answer. However, casting to non-nullable types rather than using `.Value` works perfectly! It's far from being the prettiest thing ever, but it works.